# Experience Cloud Audience Conditions

Tags: community, experience-cloud, audience

We have two audiences, `Gold|Plat` and `Group 1`. Those two audiences are used as conditions for other two `Gold|Plat Group 1` and `Not Gold|Plat Group 1`. Obviously, to be member of `Gold|Plat Group 1` you need to be member of both `Gold|Plat` and `Group 1`. And the other way around to be member of `Not Gold|Plat Group 1` you have not to be member of `Gold|Plat Group 1`, for some reason Salesforce does not allow just a single condition based on audience, hence we set the condition as not member of `Gold|Plat` or not member of `Group 1`.

[image]

The `Gold|Plat Group 1` works as expected, if user is member of both `Gold|Plat` and `Group 1` he sees content also for `Gold|Plat Group 1`.

Issue is with the `Not Gold|Plat Group 1`,

- when the user is not a member of `Gold|Plat` and `Group 1`, content for `Not Gold|Plat Group 1` won't display.
- when the user is a member of just `Gold|Plat` or just `Group 1`, content for `Not Gold|Plat Group 1` will display.
- when the user is a member of both `Gold|Plat` and `Group 1`, content is visible for both audiences `Gold|Plat Group 1` and `Not Gold|Plat Group 1`

Does anyone stumble upon this behavior before?

---

After further testing, changing the `equal` to `does not equal` does not have any effect. Looks like a bug to me.

[image]

is same as

[image]

---

Result of Salesforce support ticket:

```
I've received an update from the Product team and they've confirmed that
the issue you are facing is due to a bug. They've logged Bug# W-11530101,
to track further in detail and resolve the bug.
```

Comment: Case with Salesforce created